# Is it frequent that a tomato is thrown at a tram in Berlin/Germany?

Tags: public-transport, germany, security, berlin

When I arrived at Berlin and got on a tram and took a seat near the door, a tomato was thrown just before the door was closed.

It hit the window and two people in front of me got a broken piece of the tomato. I was safe but my big baggage got a tiny piece of the broken tomato.

The people in front of me looked rather laughing than angry. I asked a woman next to me why the tomato was thrown and she answered it is "just for fun". It is scary to say the least and pretty disgusting, never be a "fun"!

Then, when I got on another tram later, I found a trace of tomato that had been thrown at the train!

[image]

Is this "tomato terror" prevalent in Berlin? How likely is it and is it also true of other regions in Germany as well?

Anything you can do to prevent being the victim (other than staying at the middle of the tram...)?

Comment: I never witnessed anything like that. I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that school is out for summer ...

Comment: I lived in Berlin for a number of years and never had a tomato thrown at me when I was on the tram.  (Fireworks into a crowd on Silvester, yes.  Tomato on the tram, no.)

Comment: Disgusting, scary, terror?  A tomato?

Comment: @Tom Definitely!

Comment: I also searched (in English) before posting the question but got no relevant result. So I wondered if this is a recent occurrence, has not been recognized outside of German, or just a rare bad luck.

Comment: This is not something that usually happens. It's likely just some bored kids that pulled a prank, as has been said before. But Berlin and especially the public transport company BVG has a reputation of [not minding](https://youtu.be/YEYim54pJ00) people doing all kinds of crazy stuff in there. The city is just so big and anonymous that you get all kinds of people, and most of them don't really care about anyone. Mostly they just mind their own business, but there are always some weirdos. It's normal given the sample size. Just ignore it, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not a common occurrence in any part of Germany.

Looks and sounds like a silly prank.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the people were rather laughing than being startled, it means they have likely seen or heard that they were kids (fast moving light steps, gloating sniggering) which you missed.

No, it is not common at all, you are simply unlucky to experience it.